# How to import an intermediate variable from one module into another in python?

Tags: python

In module1.py i have the function calculate(), which has some intermediate variable(intermediate_variable). I want to import this intermediate_variable in module2.py. I tried setting intermediate_variable as None in module1.py but when we import it always gets the initialized value and not the updated one.

module1.py

```
def calculate():
# Perform some calculations
  intermediate_variable = 42
# doing some infinite loop operation
  while True:
    pass
```

Context: I want to import dh_exec_ctx in another module. If i cant import dh_exec_ctx in another module i would need to write all the functionalities in the same module.

```
from threading import Thread, Condition
from random import uniform
from deephaven_server import Server

dh_exec_ctx = None

cv = Condition() 

def run_deephaven():
 global dh_exec_ctx
 server = Server()
 server.start()
 from deephaven.execution_context import get_exec_ctx
 from deephaven.execution_context import make_user_exec_ctx
 with cv:
     dh_exec_ctx = get_exec_ctx()
     cv.notify()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_deephaven()
```

Comment: You can't; you would need to make `intermediate_value` a *global* variable in order to access it from the module, in which case you would probably want to pass `intermediate_value` as an *argument* to `calculate`.

Comment: Do you want to retrieve the value of `intermediate_variable` in module2 *while* `calculate` in module1 is still running and performing calculations?

Comment: updated the code by making `intermediate_variable` global but when we use 'import module1` and `var = module1.intermediate_variable` we would get `var` as `None`

Comment: @9769953 yes i want to retrieve the value of intermediate_variable in module2 while calculate in module1 is still running and performing calculations

Comment: You can't; not in a single-threaded process. The while loop is still running and performing calculations, so it's not possible to use a function somewhere else (in module2) that gets the value of `intermediate_variable` in the mean time. If you want to do this, you'll need threading and handling communication between the threads; which can become quite tricky.

Comment: Alternatively: while we don't have context, what you *actually* want may be solved in a completely different way (that is, your question may be an x-y problem), and you happen to tackle this from a wrong angle. But we can't tell, because there is no context what the actual problem is that you have, so we can't suggest a possible easier way to solve your problem.

Comment: @9769953 added context

Comment: Does `get_exec_ctx` actually *create* a new context when you call it, or does it simple return a reference to a single instance maintained by the module regardless of where you call the function from?

Comment: simply returns the reference to a single instance but we cant import it outside of the function where the server is started.That is how the package deephaven has been designed. https://deephaven.io/core/docs/tutorials/quickstart-pip/

Comment: You don't need it from the function. It's already a global variable. The function may *assign* a value to it, but importing your script from somewhere else gives you the reference, if it's not sufficient to simply call `get_exec_ctx` in the first place.